# How to select parts of a (non)function

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions

I have a set of points

```
Ainput = {{0., 0.}, {0.14, 0.049}, {0.27, 0.098}, {0.38, 0.14}, {0.47,
     0.19}, {0.56, 0.23}, {0.63, 0.28}, {0.69, 0.32}, {0.74, 
    0.36}, {0.78, 0.4}, {0.81, 0.44}, {0.83, 0.47}, {0.85, 
    0.51}, {0.86, 0.54}, {0.86, 0.58}, {0.86, 0.61}, {0.85, 
    0.64}, {0.84, 0.67}, {0.83, 0.7}, {0.81, 0.72}, {0.79, 
    0.75}, {0.77, 0.77}, {0.74, 0.8}, {0.72, 0.82}, {0.69, 
    0.84}, {0.66, 0.86}, {0.63, 0.88}, {0.61, 0.89}, {0.58, 
    0.91}, {0.56, 0.92}, {0.53, 0.94}, {0.51, 0.95}, {0.49, 
    0.96}, {0.47, 0.97}, {0.46, 0.98}, {0.44, 0.98}, {0.43, 
    0.99}, {0.42, 0.99}, {0.41, 1.}, {0.42, 0.99}, {0.43, 
    0.99}, {0.44, 0.98}, {0.46, 0.98}, {0.47, 0.97}, {0.49, 
    0.96}, {0.51, 0.95}, {0.53, 0.94}, {0.56, 0.92}, {0.58, 
    0.91}, {0.61, 0.89}, {0.63, 0.88}, {0.66, 0.86}, {0.69, 
    0.84}, {0.72, 0.82}, {0.74, 0.8}, {0.77, 0.77}, {0.79, 
    0.75}, {0.81, 0.72}, {0.83, 0.7}, {0.84, 0.67}, {0.85, 
    0.64}, {0.86, 0.61}, {0.86, 0.58}, {0.86, 0.54}, {0.85, 
    0.51}, {0.83, 0.47}, {0.81, 0.44}, {0.78, 0.4}, {0.74, 
    0.36}, {0.69, 0.32}, {0.63, 0.28}, {0.56, 0.23}, {0.47, 
    0.19}, {0.38, 0.14}, {0.27, 0.097}, {0.14, 0.049}, {0., 0.}};
```

Then i use plot

```
ListLinePlot[Ainput, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image: Plot of Ainput]

And as you can see, this is not a function. But i want to find a way how to delete the points (or lines) to have a function from these points. So in case there are lines above each other (or points) I always want to keep the one with a higher function value.

I would like to get exactly this what you can see on this picture

[image: what i want to get]

Any ideas how could I do it? Thank you for any advices.

Comment: One option is `ListLinePlot[
 Sort[Map[First@MaximalBy[#, Last] &, GatherBy[Ainput, First]]]]`, but it's very ugly code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical threshold to split the data is found by locating the peak in the reversed data

```
Arev = Reverse /@ Ainput;

thresholdVert = Arev[[FindPeaks[Arev[[All, 2]]][[All, 1]]]][[1, 1]]

(* 0.58 *)
```

Splitting the data into the upper and lower curves

```
Ainput2 = DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, First] & /@
   GatherBy[Ainput, #[[2]] < thresholdVert &];
```

The horizontal threshold to switch from one curve to the next is

```
thresholdHoriz = Min[Ainput2[[2, All, 1]]]

(* 0.41 *)
```

Define the function using [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
f[t_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{
   {Interpolation[Select[Ainput2[[1]], #[[1]] < thresholdHoriz &]][t], 
    t < thresholdHoriz}},
  Interpolation[Ainput2[[2]]][t]]

{tmin, tmax} = MinMax[Ainput[[All, 1]]]

(* {0., 0.86} *)
```

**EDIT:** The points used in the plot are just the inputs to `Interpolation`

```
pts = Join[
   Select[Ainput2[[1]], #[[1]] < thresholdHoriz &],
   Ainput2[[2]]];

Plot[f[t], {t, tmin, tmax}, Epilog -> {Red,
   AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea. I just have one more question, is it also possible to get coordinates of the points which are in the final plot? I mean the set Ainput but in the final form without the reduce points.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly shorter form of [Carl Lange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57593/carl-lange)'s comment code:

```
List @@@ Sort @ Normal @ GroupBy[Ainput, First -> Last, Max]

ListLinePlot @ %
```

> ```
> {{0., 0.}, {0.14, 0.049}, {0.27, 0.098}, {0.38, 0.14}, {0.41, 1.},
>  {0.42, 0.99}, {0.43, 0.99}, {0.44, 0.98}, {0.46, 0.98}, {0.47, 0.97},
>  {0.49, 0.96}, {0.51, 0.95}, {0.53, 0.94}, {0.56, 0.92}, {0.58, 0.91},
>  {0.61, 0.89}, {0.63, 0.88}, {0.66, 0.86}, {0.69, 0.84}, {0.72, 0.82},
>  {0.74, 0.8}, {0.77, 0.77}, {0.78, 0.4}, {0.79, 0.75}, {0.81, 0.72},
>  {0.83, 0.7}, {0.84, 0.67}, {0.85, 0.64}, {0.86, 0.61}}
> ```
>
> [image]

Is the result as you desire or are you looking for something that will handle that dip at 0.78?

Comment: Much nicer, that third argument to `GroupBy` is very smooth. Just a slightly golfier way - ListLinePlot is happy to take an association, so you can just do `ListLinePlot[KeySort[GroupBy[Ainput, First -> Last, Max]]]`

Comment: @CarlLange I like that!  A `List` may be what the OP had in mind however.